# Repaint not validating?

Tags: java, applet, repaint

Hello everyone I am quite new to applets in java and was wondering why my oval was not moving up the screen when I press the up key. I said repaint in the paint method and nothing is happening

Any Ideas? (Please don't be rude I am new to applets so...)

```
package mypackage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.applet.*;


public class gameapplet extends Applet {

    int charecterx = 500;
    int charectery = 250;


    public void init(){
        addKeyListener(new AL());
        setSize(1000,1000);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        //Paint Method
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(charecterx,charectery,100,100);
        repaint();
      }

     public class AL extends KeyAdapter
     {

            public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
            {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                //If Statements To see if user is moving
                if(keyCode == e.VK_UP)
                {

                    if(charecterx <= 0)
                    {
                    charecterx = 0;
                     }
                    else
                     {
                     charecterx--;
                     }  
                }
             }

            public void keyRealesed(KeyEvent e){

            }
     }

}
```

Comment: Code of your main method would be useful please edit your post

Comment: i don't think I have one LOL XD

Comment: @ziker It's an applet, there is no `main` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh lord i missread that good point my mistake

Comment: @ziker Wait until they do both (applet and main method)...talk about confusing :P

Answer (score 3):

You're main problem comes down to two main issues...

1- You are using a `KeyListener`

`KeyListener`s are notorious for being problematic in that they only respond to keystrokes when the component they are registered to are focusable AND have focus.

2- You never call `repaint` from within the `keyPressed` method to request that the applet be repainted.

- You should avoid `Applet` as it is woefully out of date and generally not used by many people anymore.  Instead use `JApplet`, in fact, I would recommend avoiding applets altogether until you understand the API better
- Don't call `setSize` on an applet, the size of applet is defined by the html tag it is created from.
- Don't call `repaint` or anything that might call `repaint` from within any `paint` method
- Don't override `paint`, it's too easy to break the paint chain (which you have) and for top level containers like `Applet`, isn't double buffered.  In fact AWT generally isn't double buffered, which will cause flickering when the component is repainted.  Instead, you should use something like a `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method
- Don't use `KeyListener`, it has too many issues with focus.  Instead, make use of the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which provides you with more control and a much more reusable API

Take a look at:

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

For more details

Comment: should I just double buffer it

Comment: *"Instead, you should use something like a JPanel and override it's paintComponent method"* and *"make use of the Key Bindings API which provides you with a more control and much more reusable API"*

Comment: So if I copy and pasted this into a JApplet would this code work?

Comment: Your current code won't work for the two reasons outline above.  `JApplet` (or Swing) just gives you access to a newer (in relative terms) API which has a much higher usage within the community.  Create a custom component, from something a `JPanel`.  Override it's `paintComponent`, make sure you call `super.paintComponent` first, place your custom painting here.  Make use of the Key Bindings API to introduce keyboard control and don't forget to `repaint` the panel whenever a key event occurs

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the version of your jdk.

In jdk1.6 I would use this

```
invalidate();
validate();
repaint();
```

In jdk 1.7 I would use

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Comment: `revalidate` I believe has being around since at least 1.4, probably 1.3.  `revalidate` (which simply calls `invalidate` and `validate`) deals with the layout manager API